# Netlogo: Can a turtle include another turtle?

Tags: windows, netlogo

Netlogo: Can a turtle include another turtle?
Pseudocode:
If turtle1 < 5 radius from turtle2
include turtle1 in turtle2;
turtle1 die

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by include in another turtle?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. turtle2 engulfs turtle1

Comment: "engulf" doesn't explain it any better than "include"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not exactly include, but turtles may collect a list of other unlucky agents in their own variable. Look at [agentsets](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#agentsets) in the manual.

### Example:

Declare turtle variable

```
turtles-own [
  swallowed; agentset of the turtles I've eaten
]
```

Set this agentset to empty when creating agents

```
to setup
  create-turtles 1 [ 
    set swallowed no-turtles
  ]
end
```

Enable turtles to eat each other

```
to swallow
  if any? other turtles-here [
    set swallowed (turtle-set swallowed other turtles-here) 
  ]
end
```

Ask turtles to do so:

```
to go
  ; ...

  ask turtles[ swallow ]

  ; ...
end
```

But - don't ask the swallowed turtles to die (as proposed in your pseudocode), because they will disappear from the agentsets too. Define another agent variable (for example `is-alive?`) and set it to false in the swallow procedure. You can then hide all eaten agents.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you again for your answer.
Pseudocode: 
Ifelse Turtle1 dies ;; Turtle1 and Turtle2 are from different breeds
                    ;; It is not a case of canibalism

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please don't post comments as answers - this should be deleted and submitted as a comment on the existing answer.